# Swing Error While using action listener on same button

Tags: java, swing

I want to use two same action listener with different parameters on one button.
Is it possible. ?

```
button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        String value4 = text1.getText();
        area1.setText(Integer.toString(value4.length()));
    }
});

button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {  
        String value5 = text2.getText();
        area1.setText(Integer.toString(value5.length()));
    }
});
```

Comment: Please ask if you have any questions about my answer. Also please provide more information about the "error" that you may be seeing. You tell us and show us nothing, and the error message will likely be quite instructive.

Comment: Your actions are exactly the same, instead create a method that receives the value from your `JTextField` and sets the text to the text area, no need to create one listener for each of those

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is absolutely allowed to add more than one ActionListener to a single JButton. If you're receiving an error, it is due to something else that you may not be showing us.

One problem that I see though is that both listeners call `.setText(...)` on the same JTextArea, `area1`, and so one call will overwrite and replace the text placed into the JTextArea by the other listener. It may be better to call `area1.append(...)` to avoid doing this (if `area1` is in fact a JTextArea).  This will append one String to the next String within the JTextArea.

Or another option is to combine the code into a single ActionListener, and this may be the cleanest way of doing what you want to do, because you must understand that you cannot control the *order* of how the listeners are called. That order is undefined.

Other issues:

- Most Swing `.addXxxx(...)` methods allow you to add this type of item multiple times
- While most Swing `.setXxxx(...)` methods allow you to set this property with only one item at a time, and so when this type of method is called, any previous similar property will be replaced by the new one.
- Actions are like "super-charged" ActionListeners as they do all that ActionListeners do *and more*. You can only set *one* Action to a JButton, while you can add multiple ActionListeners.
- You also can *remove* ActionListeners or Actions when need be, and this can allow you to *swap* them, very useful when you want the behavior of your button's to vary considerably depending on program state.